# connect to LAN sql server vb.net

Tags: vb.net, connection-string, sqlconnection

I'm using VB.net and trying to connect to a distant `SQL Server Database` in a LAN network, I tried several connection strings but none was successful.

The connection string I tried is this:

`Data Source=\\sage2\MSSQLSERVER,1433;Database=MATERIEL.MDF;Integrated Security=False;Network Library=dbmssocn;User Instance=False;user='" + TxtUser.Text + "';password='" + TxtPassword.Text + "'"`

Comment: Include code you have tryied, what was your real and what is your expected output then we will be able to help you.

Comment: this was my code : "Data Source=\\sage2\MSSQLSERVER,1433;Database=MATERIEL.MDF;Integrated Security=False;Network Library=dbmssocn;User Instance=False;user='" + TxtUser.Text + "';password='" + TxtPassword.Text + "'"

Comment: I'm not sure, try remove `\\\`` before `sage2` .... `Data Source=sage2\MSSQLSERVER....` ... Look into this link, too : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Have you tried to ping the server,get the IP and replace it with '\\sage2\MSSQLSERVER'?  And another thing you could try is to remove the Port number 1433 (because its standart).

Comment: make sure server has the right portforwarding settings, easiest way just to test the connection is trying to connect to the server from either server explore in Visual studio or use Sql management studio to connect. I believe you can extract connection string from server explore when succeeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is an old question, I would like to add something which might help future visitors. The answer by @Dolveras is right but you should also look at some extra things before trying to connect.

1. Allow port 1433 or whatever SQL Server is using in the firewall of the server machine for inbound and outbound requests.
2. Uncheck IPV6 in the Local Area Connection Properties on the server and client.

Thanks and Best of Coding

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to a SQL Server Your connection string should look something like this:

```
Data Source=sage2\MSSQLSERVER;Database=MATERIEL;Integrated Security=False;User Instance=False;user='" + TxtUser.Text + "';password='" + TxtPassword.Text + "'"
```

- The backslash "\" it's not necessary before the server name. \sage2 --> sage2
- The Database should be the name of the database as shown on the server,
  not the name of the file containing the data. MATERIEL.MDF --> MATERIEL
- The TCP Port is not necessary in a connection string to a named instance. \sage2\MSSQLSERVER,1433 --> SAGE2\MSSQLSERVER
- If your SQL instance is not a named instance then the Data source parameter on the connecion string has to point to the server directly. \sage2\MSSQLSERVER --> SAGE2, or you could connect using the IP and TCP port with something like *Data source=192.168.0.1,1433*